# Is it necessary to have dedicated IP Address to install SSL certificate?

Tags: asp.net, hosting, ssl-certificate, shared-hosting

I have a shared hosting plan. Now, my hosting company says it is necessary to have dedicated IP Addrss to install SSL certificate?

Is that true?

Can we install SSL certificate without dedicated IP address?

Comment: @Will, Why is this closed?

Comment: @Pacerier what (the hell) does this have to do with programming?  It's about shared hosting plans and SSL certs.  If you don't understand what is on and is off topic, we have a [help] with details.

Comment: @Will, I'm referring to points *"software tools commonly used by programmers"* and *"is
a practical, answerable problem that is unique [to software development](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8404907/where-could-i-buy-a-valid-ssl-certificate#comment-33209088)"* in the help center.

Comment: Well...here's what I believe, if we have tags like Hosting, Shared Hosting,etc. in Stackoverflow, then questions related to those should be allowed. If you really want to close, then those tags should not be created in the first place, otherwise it confuses anyone, me included.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If your server supports SNI (Server Name Indication), then you don't need a dedicated IP. The [browser support for SNI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server_Name_Indication#Support) is pretty good these days.

If your server *doesn't* support SNI, then yes; you need one dedicated IP address per certificate.
Since the SSL/TLS handshake happens before any HTTP headers (most notably the host header) are sent, there's no way that the web-server could know which certificate to send. You can host multiple domains/subdomains on one ip/port using a [SAN](http://www.digicert.com/subject-alternative-name.htm) or [wildcard](http://wiki.cacert.org/WildcardCertificates) certificate certificate but you'd still need at least one dedicated IP.

For more details, see http://blogs.iis.net/thomad/archive/2008/01/25/ssl-certificates-on-sites-with-host-headers.aspx

Comment: SNI has been around since 2003.......