# Nginx serving SSL certificate of another site

Tags: ssl, nginx, ssl-certificate

I'm serving two sites with Nginx. First site (say A) has a SSL certificate and second site (say B) doesn't. Site A works fine when opening on https and B on http. But when I access site B on https, nginx serves the SSL cert and contents of site A with domain of B, which shouldn't happen.

Nginx config for site A is as follows. For site B, it's just a reverse proxy to a Flask app.

```
server {
        listen 80;
        server_name siteA.com;
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}

server {
        listen 443 ssl;
        server_name siteA.com;

        ssl_certificate /path/to/cert.cert
        ssl_certificate_key /path/to/cert_key.key;

        ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
        ssl_ciphers ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-RC4-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:RC4-SHA:AES256-GCM-SHA384:AES256-SHA256:CAMELLIA256-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:AES128-GCM-SHA256:AES128-SHA256:AES128-SHA:CAMELLIA128-SHA;

        ssl_session_cache   shared:SSL:10m;
        ssl_session_timeout 10m;
        keepalive_timeout   70;

        # and then the `location /` serving static files
}
```

I can't figure out what is wrong here.

Comment: you can  create a ssl server for B that redirects to the non https site, should prevent the errors.

Comment: Unfortunately the ssl redirect listening on 443 only works when providing another certificate xD...
Or I did not figure out how to listen on 443 without certificate :-(
Facing the same issue, it is very annoying - exposing information which I would rather not expose to any bot just blindly trying to scan ip:443

Answer (score 2):

Apparently I need a dedicated IP for site A.

Quoting from [What exactly does "every SSL certificate requires a dedicated IP" mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15783990/what-exactly-does-every-ssl-certificate-requires-a-dedicated-ip-mean)

> When securing some connection with TLS, you usually use the certificate to authenticate the server (and sometimes the client). There's one server per IP/Port, so usually there's no problem for the server to choose what certificate to use. HTTPS is the exception -- several different domain names can refer to one IP and the client (usually a browser) connects to the same server for different domain names. The domain name is passed to the server in the request, which goes after TLS handshake. Here's where the problem arises - the web server doesn't know which certificate to present. To address this a new extension has been added to TLS, named SNI (Server Name Indication). However, not all clients support it. So in general it's a good idea to have a dedicated server per IP/Port per domain. In other words, each domain, to which the client can connect using HTTPS, should have its own IP address (or different port, but that's not usual).

Nginx was listening on port 443 and when request for site B went on https, the TLS handshake took place and the certificate of site A was presented before serving the content.

Comment: Here's a tutorial: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/articles/how-to-set-up-multiple-ssl-certificates-on-one-ip-with-nginx-on-ubuntu-12-04 It seems to rely on the server_name directive.

Answer (score 1):

The ssl_certificate parameter should be closed with **;** to get expected output.

Also make sure that you have followed the correct syntax in all the config file parameters by using following command and then restart or reload the service:

```
sudo nginx -t
```

Answer (score 0):

NGINX supports SNI, so it's possible to serve different domains with different certificates from the same IP address. This can be done with multiple server blocks. NGINX has documented this in
http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/configuring_https_servers.html

For me HTTP2 and IPv6 are important, so I to listen to [::] and set ipv6only=off. Apparently this option should only be set for the first server block, otherwise NGINX will not start.

```
duplicate listen options for [::]:443
```

These server blocks

```
server {
    listen [::]:443 ssl http2 ipv6only=off;
    server_name siteA.com www.siteA.com;

    ssl_certificate /path/to/certA.cert
    ssl_certificate_key /path/to/certA_key.key;
}
server {
    listen [::]:443 ssl http2;
    server_name siteB.com www.siteB.com;

    ssl_certificate /path/to/certB.cert
    ssl_certificate_key /path/to/certB_key.key;
}
```

Comment: It is a comment for the answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/19023457/1118709 but not an answer to the question.

Answer (score -2):

If you host multiple sites in you server and in one Nginx config if you have `listen 443 ssl http2 default_server;`

The `default_server` will give the same cert to all domains. removing it will fix the problem.

While following this [tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-secure-nginx-with-let-s-encrypt-on-ubuntu-16-04) I total missed this part:

Note: You may only have one listen directive that includes the default_server modifier for each IP version and port combination. If you have other server blocks enabled for these ports that have default_server set, you must remove the modifier from one of the blocks.

Comment: You are right about `default_server` having something to do with the problem, but are wrong about almost everything else.